# Running Start-DscConfiguration gives "the network connection to computername has been interrupted"

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, winrm, dsc

I'm running the following cmd locally on the server:

```
Start-DscConfiguration -computername mycomputer -Path C:\install -Wait -Verbose
```

The output is:

> WARNING: [WSManNetworkFailureDetected] The network connection to
>   computername has been interrupted. Attempting to reconnect for up to 4
>   minutes...

It's a new server and I've ran `Enable-PSRemoting -Force`, and the windows management service is running.

Comment: Nevermind, turns out the console wasnt running in elevated mode, that fixed it...

Comment: You should post that as an answer. It may help future readers who get that error message (since that message is not helpful in determining that the cause is related to UAC or elevation).

Comment: Definitely, post an answer and accept it as the solution!

Answer (score 0):

From [iprotocol's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4563379/iprotocol) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31810761/running-start-dscconfiguration-gives-the-network-connection-to-computername-has/49269129#comment51547026_31810761):

You need to start the console with Administrator permission.

Answer (score 0):

I started to get this error and I verified that the problem appeared to be the size of the script: when I commented a part of it, the error would go away.

Searching the web I finally found that the problem was the MOF size (over 500kb).

The solution was to run the following command before running Start-DscConfiguration:

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\MaxEnvelopeSizekb 1000
```

The answer was found here: https://powershell.org/forums/topic/dsc-configuration-size/

Note that you may have to use a greater value, depending on your case.